# Swift 5 | Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm very new to Swift 5 and studying Swift's basic concept with Stanford course in Youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZL5AmwuwlA&list=PL3d_SFOiG7_8ofjyKzX6Nl1wZehbdiZC_)

I followed after the lecture and was able to complete and understand most of the syntaxes because I had experience with typescript.

Now, I had errors at the end.

The error was as follow:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton copyWithZone:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9279d0c120' terminating
> with uncaught exception of type NSException CoreSimulator 732.18.6 -
> Device: iPhone 8 (84D717C3-B6FA-4AC7-94A0-475F1BD8F83E) - Runtime: iOS
> 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 8

My code is as below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
 var flipCount = 0 {
     didSet {
         flipCountLabel.text = "Flips: \(flipCount)"
     }
 }
     
 @IBOutlet weak var flipCountLabel: UILabel!
 
 @IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!
 
 var emojiChoices = ["", "", "", ""]
 
 @IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
     flipCount += 1
     if let cardNumber = cardButtons.firstIndex(of: sender) {
         flipCard(withEmoji: emojiChoices[cardNumber], on: sender)
     } else {
         print("chosen card was not in cardButtons")
     }
 }

 
 func flipCard(withEmoji emoji:String, on button:UIButton) {
     if(button.currentTitle == emoji) {
         button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
         button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
     } else {
         button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControl.State.normal)
         button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
     }
 }


}
```

I feel like I don't understand what they meant when it says "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9279d0c120"

Please help me out TT

Comment: This is caused by wrong connections from the storyboard to the ViewController, check that every button is connected to the right outlet in VC

Comment: Oh, what do you mean by  @IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]! ? Why is it an array of buttons? What are you trying to achieve?